# How to implement jsf 2.0 functionality in jsf 1.2

Tags: jsf-2, oracle-adf, jsf-1.2

We need to implement **JSF** **2.0** functionality in **JSF** **1.2**

1)FacesContext.getAttributes() 
2)UIViewRoot.getViewRoot()

Version of Jdeveloper we are using is 11.1.1.7.0.
The above two should be implemented in JSF 1.2.

Any ideas/suggestions are highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,
Sarvani.

Comment: This doesn't make sense for me. Please provide a more detailed use case description. I could not find a method getViewRoot() in class UIViewRoot. Why not using jsf2?

Answer (score 0):

we cannot use JSF2, because we are using Jdeveloper 11.1.1.7 version so JSF 1.2.
We need to use the below functionality for the logging purpose.

1. FacesContext.getAttributes()
2. UIViewRoot.getViewMap()

As these are introduced in JSF2 , Any Idea/suggestions how to achieve the same functionality in JSF 1.2

-Jagadeesh Badri